# can I manually block some git commit options, like "-a"?

Tags: git

I should not use `git commit -a` sometime, so I wonder is there a way to block it?

or let's say something like a switch for this?

Comment: Are you saying you want to configure git such that when you type `git commit -a`, it ignores the `-a` and runs `git commit` instead?

Comment: @ChristopherMartin yeah, kind of.

Comment: @bitsMix Why would you wanna do that?? If you don't want `-a` to be there, then simply don't type it!

Comment: @bitsMix: That is, in case you screw up??!! :P :P

Comment: @bitsMix I know the feeling!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an aside, instead of "blocking" `git commit -a` from happening, you could just get used to NOT doing it, and if you do it on accident, follow it up with a `git reset HEAD^` and try the commit again.

Otherwise, here are two methods:

If you use `--no-all` as the last argument to `git commit`, it will cancel any `-a` (which means `--all` specified earlier in the command line. Example:

Commit everything:

```
git commit -a
```

Don't really commit everything:

```
git commit -a --no-all
```

As to how to make this get appended to any `git commit` command automatically, I'm not sure an easy way other than some shell magic (e.g. a smart wrapper for the `git` command), as git will not let you set an alias for `commit` because it is a built-in command.

Using the append-"--no-all" trick unfortunately breaks the `git commit args... --- files...` form. So here is another way:

Here is a wrapper you can put in your path. Call it `git` and make sure it is in your path BEFORE the "real" git, and point `PATH_TO_GIT` at the real git.

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH_TO_GIT=/usr/bin/git

if [ "$1" = "commit" ]; then
    exec $PATH_TO_GIT "${@/#-a/}"
else
    exec $PATH_TO_GIT "$@"
fi
```

This does have some limitations, but it seems like it will do what you want.

Comment: For bash you can use `function gitCommit() { git commit ${@} --no-all }`

Comment: @Sebastian that works, but it doesn't solve the OP's (I assume) problem of accidentally typing `git commit -a` and not meaning it. Of course the best fix is "stop doing that". =)

Comment: He would have to use `gitCommit` instead of `git commit`. But you are right, just don't commit everything if you don't want to commit everything.

Comment: @Sebastian I updated the answer with an admonition to just stop doing it, as well as how to recover if you do it accidentally. Personally I think the OP will be better off with that than with a wrapper hack, but hey, whatever works for them. =)

Comment: i guess this is the right way for now. thanks for your great answer @wjl ;)